# Why is there no real Wallet Plugin for Firefox

Tags: cip30, dapp-bridge

It seems that wallets are not able to implement cip30 for firefox, what is the hurden to do it, and why does it work for chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This has been an issue since a long time. At least for Nami, it is possible to add the extension to Firefox, but the performance is horrible.

See: https://github.com/berry-pool/nami/issues/68

It seems like no one took the time to look into this yet even though there are quite some users requesting Firefox support.

Comment: so it is technically possible but there is just not enough demand?

Comment: Yes, it is for sure technically feasible. Ethereum wallets like Metamask also work in Firefox.

Comment: i mean not a wallet it self, i mean the CIP-30 connector, which enables websites to communicate with the wallet